# TCP Socket connected false

Tags: c#, sockets

So while debugging my application I came across a strange problem where Socket Connected property returns false even when socket is connected.
Any call to send works fine and at the moment this happens there is a thread doing a receive without any errors.

In MS doc they state that

> The Connected property gets the connection state of the Socket as of the last I/O operation. When it returns false, the Socket was either never connected, or is no longer connected.

But then

> The value of the Connected property reflects the state of the connection as of the most recent operation. If you need to determine the current state of the connection, make a non-blocking, zero-byte Send call. If the call returns successfully or throws a WAEWOULDBLOCK error code (10035), then the socket is still connected; otherwise, the socket is no longer connected.

Even with that being said all the last operation would have to complete successfully so the property should be equal to true.
So what should I make of this? It's not enough to check the Connected property?

Comment: Not a direct explanation for the behavior, but: I've rarely if ever seen code that used `Socket.Connected` and wasn't actually wrong. The only sensible measure of "connectedness" is whether or not operations on it fail, and if they do, you should close the socket (at which point they'll automatically fail). Checking `Connected` in advance is mostly pointless because it won't tell you if an operation will actually succeed, and so for the most part it's just overhead -- typically, trying to use a socket that's no longer usable is not an operation that you need to optimize for.

Comment: Ok so you saying that the property is unreliable ? In general the disconnection can be and will be detected as there is always a thread that block on Read so yes an error there is used by me to detect disconnection, sure enough same can be done with Send but it was just a surprise to see for me that the property is wrong.

Comment: To be clear, `.Connected` *should* at least reflect the writability of the socket as far as the OS is concerned (it uses `select()` under the covers), so it should be reliable in the *negative* sense, but because it's not useful in the positive sense I've never found much use for that either. Closing a socket on an error cancels existing operations and prevents new ones from succeeding, which is overall more reliable than anything that could be done with `.Connected`.